# Как добавить вложенность в объект js?

Tags: javascript

Есть

```
    var abc = {
      a: "50",
      b: "51",
      c: () => {},
      d: () => {},
      e: () => {}
    };
```

Надо преобразовать в

```
    var abc2 = {
      a: "50",
      b: "51",
      functions: {
         c: () => {},
         d: () => {},
         e: () => {}
      }
    };
```

Comment: Какой результат вы хотите получить? И что не получилось?

Comment: перебрать abc и вынести функции в отдельную вложенность

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает тот вариант, который вы написали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var abc = {
  a: "50",
  b: "51",
  c: () => {},
  d: () => {},
  e: () => {}
};
// Object.entries раскладывает объект на массивы ключ-значение
// reduce проходится по массиву, складываем всё в объект obj
abc = Object.entries(abc).reduce((obj, [key, val]) => {
  // если встречаем не функцию - записываем как есть
    if (typeof val !== 'function') {
    obj[key] = val
  } else { // если встречаем функцию - записываем в obj.functions
    // если obj.functions нет - создаём параметр = пустой объект
    // можно в инициализации прописать свойство ({functions: {}}), тогда
    // условие не нужно, но придется сортировать свойства, если это важно
    if (!obj.functions) obj.functions = {} 
    obj.functions[key] = val
  }
  return obj //передаём объект в следующую итерацию
}, {})

console.log(abc)
```

Comment: Замурчательно))

Comment: Спасибище! То, что надо!